# Switching from Python 3 to 2 in a runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, os.execl

I try to check if current version is 3 and if so, switch to python2:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, os

if sys.version_info[0] != 2:
    os.execl("/usr/bin/", "python2", *sys.argv)

print(sys.version_info[:])
```

But this script returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./a.py", line 6, in <module>
    os.execl("/usr/bin/", "python2", *sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/os.py", line 531, in execl
    execv(file, args)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

What have I missed?

Comment: run this script as administartor, may help..

Comment: Nope. And it wont have root privilages in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > os.execl("/usr/bin/", "python2", *sys.argv)

/usr/bin/ is a directory, you can't run it.  Try:

> > os.execl("/usr/bin/python2", "/usr/bin/python2", *sys.argv[1:])

Answer (score 0):

I would argue what you are attempting is a bad idea - it is surprising behaviour and not needed, instead, simply use an explicit hashbang:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
```

Or, preferably:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

As per [PEP 394](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/), any unix system should provide `python2`.

Comment: Well, that's the point - python doesn't have python2 symlink in OSX.

Comment: @ciembor Then I would recommend contacting the maintainer of that package and suggesting they fix that bug. The PEP is quite clear - *"Unix-like software distributions (including systems like Mac OS X and Cygwin) should install the python2 command into the default path whenever a version of the Python 2 interpreter is installed, and the same for python3 and the Python 3 interpreter."*.